# Nginx server replaces /etc/hosts file

Tags: nginx, hosts

I begin and I do not see how to explain my problem. I have a `/etc/hosts` file like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       a.com
192.x.x.x       b.com
```

I need to replace this line `192.x.x.x       b.com`of my `/etc/hosts` file with a Nginx server. Thanks to a database, I have access to Ip and port addresses.
Here is my nginx.conf:

```
 server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /e/ {
        default_type 'text/plain';
        set $ip '';
        set $port '';

        rewrite_by_lua_block {

            ip = ngx.location.capture("/getIp", {
                    method = ngx.HTTP_GET
            })
            port = ngx.location.capture("/getPort", {
                    method = ngx.HTTP_GET
            })

            ngx.var.ip = ip;
            ngx.var.port = port;
        }
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass http://$ip:$port/;
    }
```

However, when I remove the hosts line, it does not work anymore.